# Class not found exception while trying to call Java code in a QT project

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, jar

I am trying to use some code written in Java in a QT Creator project for an Android application. My end goal here is to use classes and methods created with Android Studio in this project.

To test if I understood the QT Java wrapper class I created a Java class from the Android Studio:

File>>New module>>Android Library>>Finish

In this library I created a class as follows:

```
package com.example.testclass;

public class MyJavaClass {
   public static int fibonacci (int n){
       if (n <2)
           return n;
       return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
   }
}
```

Then 'Build>>Make module'

In my QT project .pro file I added: **QT += androidextras** and copied **.aar** file (also tried unzipping and copying the **.jar** file-likewise tried copying **...\testclass\src\main** too) to **javalib\**  directory in my project file. 
Now at this point I tried numerous things to make this file visible to my project. I edited .pro file by adding:

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    javalib/java/com/example/testclass/MyJavaClass.java \
    javalib/AndroidManifest.xml
```

I tried to add files through gradle file that already existed in the project and several other things which I cannot remember.

But nevertheless following code to call the 'fibonacci' method from 'MyJavaClass';

```
void MainWindow::on_javaButton_clicked()
{
    int fibo = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>("com/example/testclass/MyJavaClass", "fibonacci", "(I)I", 5);
    qDebug() << "JAVA OUTPUT: " << fibo << endl;
}
```

Throws class not found exception at run time:

```
W System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.testclass.MyJavaClass" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
W System.err:   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
W System.err:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
W System.err:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:390)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:61)
W System.err:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
D libBlueToothTest.so: JAVA OUTPUT:  0
```

I tried using docs from QT site and other sources like https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/BogdanVatra_Extending_Qt_Android_Apps_with_JNI.pdf.

I am new to QT, Android and Java. **Despite the documents and examples I am struggling with this and I would appreciate any help.**

My .pro file as of now:

```
QT       += core gui bluetooth androidextras

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    BlueTooth/BlueToothManager.cpp \
    BlueTooth/bluetoothclient.cpp \
    BlueTooth/bluetoothserver.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \

HEADERS += \
    BlueTooth/BlueToothManager.h \
    BlueTooth/bluetoothclient.h \
    BlueTooth/bluetoothserver.h \
    mainwindow.h \

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

OTHER_FILES += \
    javalib/java/com/example/testclass/MyJavaClass.java \
    javalib/AndroidManifest.xml

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew \
    android/gradlew.bat \
    android/res/values/libs.xml

contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,armeabi-v7a) {
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = \
        $$PWD/android
}
```

My gradle file as of now:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qt5AndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was working on this for far too long. After a lot of trial and error I finally got a solution to this problem. Code for Java nor the C++ side has any problems. Problem is somewhere in gradle or AndroidManifest files.

-I copied **...\AndroidStudioProjects\qtTest\testclass\src\main\java** file(contains concatenated folders as per 'package' keyword in Java code also the .java source file) to my Android package directory which in my case was **android\** (see next step)

-To call Java methods and classes from QT project you need to add an android package directory to .pro file(I already had one at the bottom which just points to "android" folder in my project directory). I don't know exactly what that file included at the beginning. I assumed it was about wrapping C++ code to build a program for Android. Anyways...

-Next step is to have a correct template for the program. **Projects>>Build Steps>>Build Android APK>>Create Templates** Takes you to template wizard which already has a package source directory taken from .pro file. I did not remove the tick to "Copy the Gradle files to Android directory" however I don't know if it makes any difference.

-Overwrite everything wizard asks you.

And voilà one clean build after code works without problems!